# newbie: simpleform, how to set id for a collection input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

`How would one set`:id => "myvalue" for a simpleform *collection* input field? 
and or on a sidenote, im also trying to set the ID of age_from like id => "age_from" cannot figure out how to do both, seems very lacking docs on these.

Tried all possible combinations I could comeup with:

```
= f.input_field :age_to,
  :label => "Age from",
  :collection => 18..60,
  :select => 19 <------- set this to '19' for this collection?
  :style => "width: 50px !important",
  :id => "myid" <------- how to set id for this collection?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f.input_field :age_to, :label => "Age from", :collection => 18..60, 
:selected => 19, :style => "width: 50px !important", :input_html => { :id => "myid" }
```

Hope it works to set `id` and show selected value!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SimpleForm, then:

```
= f.input :age_to, .., :input_html => { :id => 'myid' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
= f.input :age_to, :label => "Age from", :collection => 18..60, :value_method => 19, :input_html => { :id => 'myid' }
```